# How to mirror the privileges of an user to another in Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, sqlplus, permissions

I need to grant all the privileges of a user (say 'AAA') to another user (say 'BBB').

Is there such an Oracle command (11.2.0.3.0)?

Answer (score 6):

Get all privileges from AAA

```
 SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('ROLE_GRANT','AAA') FROM DUAL;

 SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('SYSTEM_GRANT','AAA') FROM DUAL;

 SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('OBJECT_GRANT','AAA') FROM DUAL;
```

Change the DDL commands with the user 'BBB' and execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
expdp userid=system directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=AAA.dmp schemas=AAA
impdp userid=system directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=AAA.dmp remap_schema=AAA:BBB
```

or make use of dbms_metadata

[user_ddl.sql](http://www.oracle-base.com/dba/script_creation/user_ddl.sql)